# How to edit speed of a 'projectile' in an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to edit the speed of a projectile when the high score goes up 30. However, the code is running fine and the game is working as per normal but the speed at which the projectile moves is still the same.

```
 let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

    // Setting up the initial location of projectile
    let particle2 = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "smoke.sks")
    let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "inky")
    projectile.position = player.position
    particle2!.targetNode = self
    projectile.addChild(particle2!)

    projectile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: projectile.size.width/2)
    projectile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.projectile
    projectile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.monster
    projectile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none
    projectile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    // Determine offset of location to projectile
    let offset = touchLocation - projectile.position

    // Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
    if offset.x < 0 { return }

    // OK to add now - you've double checked position
    addChild(projectile)

    // Get the direction of where to shoot
    let direction = offset.normalized()

    // Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
    let shootAmount = direction * 1000

    // Add the shoot amount to the current position
    let realDest = shootAmount + projectile.position

    // Create the actions
    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: 2.0)
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    projectile.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))

     if UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "highscore") >= 30 {
        let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: 1.0)

}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? If so, what have you discovered? This should be part of your question. SO is a terrible debugger!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm no expert in SpriteKit or iOS games at all. There is very likely to be a better solution.

What you have tried already seems sensible apart from calling `SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: 2.0)` before you have checked the score.

I think you would be better doing something like this:

```
let highScore = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "highscore")
let duration: CGFloat = highScore >= 30 ? 1.0 : 2.0
let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: duration)
// add move end, run the animation
```

The only logical change is the duration of the movement to simulate speed, so work this value out beforehand based on your game logic and then just pass it in

Comment: thank you for answering but when I tried that, and some variations it did not work

Comment: can you try to print the highScore and duration values before the line `let actionMove = ..` see what values you are getting?

Comment: nothing changes but I get a 'Initialization of immutable value 'actionMove' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it' error

Comment: you still need the other lines below... `let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    projectile.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))`